# Access ajax elements with django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

i am using ajax to fetch django model and get results

views.py

```
def browse_jobs(request):
    keyword = request.GET.get('keyword', None)
    company = Company.objects.filter(title__icontains=keyword)
    data = serializers.serialize("json", company, fields=('title'))
    return JsonResponse({'data':data,})
```

ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/browse_jobs',
    data: {
      'keyword': keyword,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data) {
        console.log(data.title);
      }
    }
});
```

and i am getting this response from django

```
{"data": "[{\"model\": \"app.company\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {\"title\": \"Facebook\"}}, {\"model\": \"app.company\", \"pk\": 2, \"fields\": {\"title\": \"Fabook\"}}]"}
```

my question is how i can access the title.

Comment: Looks like you "double serialized" the response: instead of serializing the value, let the JSONing only happens once.

Comment: how i can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You here *double* serialized the value for the `"data"` key: first by the `serializers.serialize(..)` that constructed a string, and the you again serialize it (constructing an string literal), making it harder to obtain the elements.

We can prevent this, for examply by turning the JSON blob back into a *vanilla* Python object first:

```
from json import loads as json_loads

def browse_jobs(request):
    keyword = request.GET.get('keyword', None)
    company = Company.objects.filter(title__icontains=keyword)
    data = serializers.serialize("json", company, fields=('title'))
    return JsonResponse({'data': json_loads(data), })
```

Then the AJAX call will receive a JSON blob where `"data"` does *not* map to a string, but a list of subdictionaries, making it easier accessible.

Here there are *two* results for your query, you can print the *first* `title` with:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/browse_jobs',
    data: {
      'keyword': keyword,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.data[0].fields.title);
    }
});
```

Comment: it worked but can you tell me how to access the title

Comment: @ChamsAgouni: well here there are *two* elements in the queryset (two companies) so there are *multiple* `title`s.

Comment: for example i want to access first title

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined error

Comment: @ChamsAgouni: what does it show for a `console.log(data);`

Comment: when i type in my input it show Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined

Comment: @ChamsAgouni: yes, but what does `console.log(data);` (so the result) shows. Looks to me that it does return an *empty* list of results.

Comment: it shows Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: But the `data` is a parameter in the function... What is the response the AJAX call does?

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: All modern browsers have a *network console*, you can track AJAX requests, and thus inspect the request and the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178362/discussion-between-chams-agouni-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: IT SHOWS XHR in type